# How do I embed a URL in an image in HTML?

Tags: html, image, url, embed

I'm looking to be able to click on an image and for it to redirect me to another html page. This page is not stored in the website directory root. I tried the following code, but got a 404 error.

```
<a href="/home/tyler/Documents/hfm/website/index.html"><img src= "fahlogo.png" /></a>
```

Comment: What's the url you use to access to this page in your browser? It would be the url to put in the <a> link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

Apache's [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) allows you to map other file paths to the web path.  For example:

```
Alias /mydocs /home/tyler/Documents/hfm/website
```

This will tell apache to serve a request to `/mydocs/index.html` to look under /home/tyler/Documents/hfm/website/index.html.  So then you could use:

```
<a href="/mydocs/index.html"><img src= "fahlogo.png" /></a>
```

---

Use a relative URL:

```
<a href="/index.html"><img src= "fahlogo.png" /></a>
```

This will point to `http://mywebsite.com/index.html`.  If you need, say, `http://mywebsite.com/app/index.html`, then you would use:

```
<a href="/app/index.html"><img src= "fahlogo.png" /></a>
```

Comment: It's not working, and that's the exact same code I was using before. Remember, my website's root is NOT the same as the location of this .html file.

Directory root (fahlogo.png) : /etc/apache2
HFM root (index.html) : /home/tyler/Documents/hfm/website/index.html

Comment: @TylerMontney oh, I see now.  I guess you need the "Alias" command -- see my edit above.

Comment: Alright so it worked, but I have a problem when creating more than one. I'd like to have multiple Aliases. For whatever reason, it is giving me the same 404 error for any new Aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip if the file is right above the current folder, you can tell the browser to move up one folder by putting "../" in front of your file name. Example:

```
<a href="../index.html"><img src= "fahlogo.png" /></a>
```